# Is Linq "Where" more expensive than Linq "Select"?

Tags: c#, linq, performance, select, collections

I'm investigating performance on an operation. I'm iterating a subset of items from a collection. I filter this collection using a Linq query. It basically looks like this:

```
var filteredItems = items.Where(x => x.PropertyToFilterOn == filterValue);
foreach (var filteredItem in filteredItems)
{
    // do something to the filtered item
}
```

If I use `Select` instead of `Where` I achieve the same thing. Which is better to use and what is the difference?

Comment: The question is based on the assumption that Select and Where achieves the same thing, but that is not true, so the question of their performance is moot.

Comment: Should have gotten my facts straight before posting this question. Apologies and thanks for the answers and comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where and Select certainly do not achieve the same thing.

`Where` filters the enumerable based on a predicate. The result of calling Where on `IEnumerable<T>` is `IEnumerable<T>`.

`Select` is a projection - it allows you to map the enumerable, for example to select only a subset of the properties of the enumerated type, or construct a different object entirely based upon values of the enumerated type.

Both where and select are at least O(n) - since each item in the enumeration will have to be visited to perform the projection or the filter.

The following document on the Standard Query Operators is a great reference.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/8/6/5868081c-68aa-40de-9a45-a3803d8134b8/standard_query_operators.doc

Answer (score 5):

`Where` filters, `Select` maps. Two totally different things.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @Johannes: the question asserts something that is wrong.  This corrects taht aeertions, essentially marking the question as invalid.  Yes it should probably be a comment, but isn't a totally invalid answer.

Comment: @Johannes: Doesn't it? The difference is that they do different things, so obviously the better one to use is the one that actually does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Compare how the background code in theory would work:

```
// Where
foreach(var x in items)
{
    if (x.PropertyToFilterOn == filterValue)
        yield return x;
}

// Select
foreach (var x in items)
{
    yield return selector(x);
}
```

So mind you, the performance difference is based on the complexity of the given selector delegate. But as others have said, they serve different purposes.